# How do I avoid counting new lines as words in spark?

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark

I'm trying to run the word count example on lorem ipsum; i.e. count *words* frequencies in a given text file. As the rule of words splitting I would like to use any instance of non-character. I have the following python code:

```
import re
from pyspark import SparkContext
print "-----------------===========================-----------------"
print "-----------------==========Staring==========-----------------"
print "-----------------===========================-----------------"
sc = SparkContext(appName = "simple app")

print "-----------------===========================-----------------"
print "-----------------==========Loaded file======-----------------"
print "-----------------===========================-----------------"
text_file = sc.textFile("lorem.txt")

print "-----------------===========================-----------------"
print "-----------------==========  Process  ======-----------------"
print "-----------------===========================-----------------"
counts = text_file.flatMap(lambda line: re.split(r'\W*', line.rstrip())) \
         .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
         .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b) \
         .map(lambda (a,b): (b, a)) \
         .sortByKey(False)

output = counts.collect()
counts.saveAsTextFile("test.txt")
sc.stop()
for x in output:
    print (x[0], x[1])
```

It works almost as expected. The main problem is that it counts the new lines. If I understand correctly this is due to the way the regex works, but I cannot find a workaround. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you want to achieve...do you want to count all words?

Comment: I'm trying to count the word frequencies. However, the code above treats a newline as a word.

Comment: What is the content of `lorem.txt`..did you try `\W+`

Comment: @vks: http://www.lipsum.com/. Tried `\W+` as well. Same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `line.rstrip()` only strips whitespace.  But it can take a parameter as in `line.rstrip(badchars)` that will strip everything in `badchars`.

Even if newlines make it into the RDD, along with empty words and other junk, you can always filter them out by adding a [`RDD.filter()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/api/python/pyspark.rdd.RDD-class.html#filter) step to your workflow.  `filter` calls a function for each element of the RDD and returns an RDD of elements that returned `true`.

A couple of ways to get rid of newline as a word:

Look for it explicitly

```
counts = text_file.flatMap(lambda line: re.split(r'\W*', line.rstrip())) \
         .filter(lambda word: word!="\n") \
         .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
         .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b) \
         .map(lambda (a,b): (b, a)) \
         .sortByKey(False)
```

Filter on word length > 1 char

```
counts = text_file.flatMap(lambda line: re.split(r'\W*', line.rstrip())) \
         .filter(lambda word: len(word)>1) \
         .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
         .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b) \
         .map(lambda (a,b): (b, a)) \
         .sortByKey(False)
```

Comment: You can experiment with the lambda function for filter to get what you want.   The first one only blocks words exactly equal to "\n".  Perhaps `"\n" not in word` would be a better test?  The second one will block short words, including a few actual words, such as "A", "I", and "O".